# Is it possible to access configuration objects from config.exs in dev.exs?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

### Context

I have a user-supplied object of configurations in `config/config.exs`. It turns out I need a user-supplied url into the `dev.exs` file.

Technically, this value could be an environment Docker variable, but I'm trying to make `config.exs` the single source of truth.

### Problem

I can't do it.

I'm thinking there's no way to do it. Am I wrong?

### Update/More Info

I have the following master config in `config/config.exs`

```
config :data, Document,
  deployment: %{
    local_host: "somehost",
    swarm_host: "otherhost
  }
```

I would to access the values for the `deployment` map in another config file loaded after the definition of the master config, using an `import_config` statement. The file `dev.exs` is loaded **after** `config.exs`.

Now in `dev.exs`, I need to access the hosts of the `deployment` map, but sadly `Application.get_env(:data, Document)` is nil (which most likely means the loading of all configuration variables is not done yet), 
meaning I can't get access any config variables defined in the other config file. I'm quite sure there's no workaround for this, but maybe there is a clever solution beyond me.

I thought it was evident that I had researched about this online, search the Phoenix docs for configuration files and found nothing useful and that's why I'm in SO, but apparently wasn't that evident for some.

Comment: Generally, user-supplied information should not go in the config files. Your *.exs configuration files are for build configuration and supplying test modules for mocking behaviours. However, could you provide any code examples of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci thank you for your valuable contribution. I have added a tiny code sample and provided extra context which is far more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read a variable from one config file in another, you can use  `import_config` in `dev.exs`:

```
use Mix.Config

import_config "config.exs"
```

Anything defined above the `import_config` line will get overriden, and anything defined below it will override whatever came from the imported file.

Be aware that *everything* from the `config.exs` file will get imported, so perhaps you want to create a `config_user.exs` and import that from every other configuration file in case you only want certain variable shared.

Comment: Crap! I was using the `import_config` command on the other side of the problem, because of the way Phoenix handles the `dev.exs` file. This will lead to what I want. Thanks!